# TSQL for Repeating rows within table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have single table with below fields.

```
id    name          startdate                enddate
1     u1      2013-01-15 00:00:00.000   2013-01-17 00:00:00.000
2     u2    2013-01-22 00:00:00.000         2013-01-23 00:00:00.000
3     u3    2013-01-23 00:00:00.000         2013-01-23 00:00:00.000
```

Now, I want multiple rows depends on start and end dates. So as per above rows.. It returns with three rows for first record.. date 15 to 17 which returns 3 rows (3 days).

I am bit confused for query. Is there any better way or any sample to achieve?

Thanks.

Comment: Any help? I am not sure if this question should be down rated..? its valid logical question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, may be as you have not shown any efforts. Do you need to filter results by Id?

Comment: @Kaf Thanks.. Below is what I have tried.. You can give your answer different if you have or you can do!

Comment: Please add what you have tried to the question rather than an answer. I am trying to clarify if you need to filter the data by Id (ie, passing a parameter) or a query for the whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CTE to solve that:

```
DECLARE @Id int
SELECT  @Id = 1
;

WITH    Multiple AS
(
        SELECT  1 Sequence, Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate
        FROM    (       VALUES
                (1, 'u1', '2013-01-15', '2013-01-17'),
                (2, 'u2', '2013-01-22', '2013-01-23'),
                (3, 'u3', '2013-01-23', '2013-01-23')
        )       AS Sample(Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate)
        WHERE   Id = @Id
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  Sequence + 1, Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate
        FROM    Multiple
        WHERE   Id = @Id AND DATEADD(d, Sequence, StartDate) <= EndDate
)
SELECT  *  
FROM    Multiple
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 'Dates' table with a 'Date' column in there, just join your table to the 'Dates' on 'Dates.Date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure but below is what I have tried..

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM master..spt_values p 
    INNER JOIN tempQuery c1
        ON RIGHT(CAST(c1.stdate AS DATE),2) <= (CASE WHEN p.number = 0 THEN 1 ELSE p.number END)
WHERE TYPE='p'
AND p.number BETWEEN RIGHT(CAST(c1.stdate AS DATE),2) AND RIGHT(CAST(c1.endate AS DATE),2)
```